# Why can't I get the wire to latch when replacing Nikon D5100 focusing screen?

Tags: nikon-d5100, diy, focusing-screen

I acquired an aftermarket Bresson focusing screen for my Nikon D5100. I very carefully followed the instructions to remove the old screen. However, I find that I can not get the wire retainer to latch again. I put it behind the latch, it pops out. Before I put my tail between my legs and head for the repair store, can anyone suggest another course of action? I can't even get the latch to stay put with no screen in place at all.

Comment: [YouTube: Installing Nikon D5100 Focusing Screen](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=installing+Nikon+D5100+focusing+screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

When I went to lock down the screen, I forgot that the wire bail needed to go inside the latch. I tried to latch it by having it go outside the latch, where it very sensibly declined to stay.

Comment: If you think you found a solution, you can accept it yourself I guess.